# Sort points along the quadrangle's perimeter

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

For calculation of [centroid of quadrangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon), points need to be sorted in order of their occurrence along the ***quadrangle***'s perimeter. Having 4 points *p1, p2, p3, p4* with coordinate *x, y* for each such point, so with *p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, ...* what is the most efficient way to sort points along perimeter?

Formula or algorithm in any programming language is welcome, Javascript is preferred.

Comment: Do points form a convex quadrangle? In the other case the problem is ambiguous.

Comment: @user502144 - ***Any*** 4 points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2122620/502144 can help to solve the problem. However, it doesn't consider the order of points, only point set. Here is the modified table with the ordering:

```
ABC  ABD  BCD  CAD  hull
------------------------
 +    +    +    -   ABCD
 +    +    -    +   ABDC
 +    -    +    +   ACBD
```

ABC, ABD, BCD, CAD are orientations of triangles. Cases with 4 points forming a convex quadrangle are only considered. In other cases any ordering is be valid resulting in non-convex quadrangle.