# Python: Drawing an area based on opposite geographic coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, coordinates

I try to plot and connect points in in the shape of a rectangle, but I am doing something wrong.

I have vectors of coordinates like this:

`x = [6.2372045620000005, 6.237194762000001, 6.237194762000001, 6.2372045620000005]`

`y = [51.071833453, 51.071835828999994, 51.071833453, 51.071835828999994]`

First, I plot point data:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'blue')
```

[image]

Then, I try to add line between points in such a way, that a rectangle is formed. Unfortunately this below does not work correctly.

```
plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'blue')
plot.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Do you know what I am doing wrong? It's a simple thing for sure, but I'm stuck with that..

Thanks for you help and comments.

Comment: **[Don't Post Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. It's likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You're discouraging assistance, as no one wants to retype data/code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Plots are ok. See [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246).

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and show your effort.

Comment: What do you mean with "on opposite values"? I think you can easily find the coordinates of other corners, right? Then just plot a line which pass on all corners.

Comment: Hi @GiacomoCatenazzi I just edited my post, would you please take a look again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is assumed that the coordinates, for any shape, are already ordered.

If you're confident that you have a rectangle (all right corners, not some quadrilateral) you can take the min/max values of your x and y coordinates to get the correct corner points. Given the coordinates that you already defined in your post:

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xmin = min(x)
xmax = max(x)
xsize = xmax - xmin

ymin = min(y)
ymax = max(y)
ysize = ymax - ymin
```

Using Matplotlib, you can either use the `Rectangle` patch like:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=86)
ax.scatter(x, y, color='blue')

rect = patches.Rectangle(
    (xmin, ymin), xsize, ysize, 
    lw=2, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none',
)
ax.add_patch(rect)
```

Or the `Polygon` patch, for any arbitrary shape. Both methods will work in this case:

```
points = [
    (xmin, ymin),
    (xmax, ymin),
    (xmax, ymax),
    (xmin, ymax),
]

poly = patches.Polygon(
    points, lw=2, edgecolor='r', facecolor='#ff000011', closed=True,
)
ax.add_patch(poly)
```

[image]

If you do have something less regular shaped, like a quadrilateral, calculating the convex-hull might help getting the correct order of the coordinates. See for example:
[Convex hull of 4 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122305/convex-hull-of-4-points)